# Class path entry is missing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am using Eclipse, Helios Service Release 2, Build id: 20110218-0911.

I have created a new dynamic web site, I have added google app engine sdks in it. now i shows the following msg in problem window,

```
Classpath entry com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.
```

due to this, jar files in sdk are not coming in lib folder of WEB-INF,

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: How did you add the GAE SDKS's to your project?

Comment: right click project --> Google -- > app engine settings -- > check use google app engine

Answer (score 30):

Right click on this warning in the problems (or markers) view and select quick fix. There is a quick fix available for this problem that will tag the classpath entry for inclusion in the web app, which is what you want. You can also control what's included in the web app by using Deployment Assembly page under your web app's project properties.

Comment: The "Quick Fix" solved it. But in my case I took the choice to "exclude" it, rather than "include" it. It was happy to have my choice and the flag went away.

Comment: Worked for me but what is actually going on?

Comment: For a web application, Eclipse needs to know which classpath entries you expect to be available on your application server vs bundled with the application. The warning indicates that this information has not been provided. The default behavior is not to bundle, which may or may not be correct, hence the warning.

Comment: Any way to do this in bulk?  I have 63 of these and Quick Fix doesn't work unless only one is selected. It appears to be adding a ton of XML to the .classpath file just to specify it's a non-dependency

Comment: When you click Quick Fix, then choose to Exclude it. Including it will result in an error - something about already having that dependency declared elsewhere.